# Simple probability related question

Tags: probability

I started reading All of Statistics by Larry Wasserman and have a question regarding Example 1.13:

A medical test for a disease D has outcomes + and −. The
probabilities are:

[image]

What is $P(D)$? According to the calculations showed later:

$P(D) = 0.009 + 0.001 = P(D\cap+) +P(D\cap -) = P(D\cap(+\cup -))$

So it seems that $+\cup- = \Omega $. Is is true? If so, why?

I'm not sure what is the sample space here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the disease $D$ has two possible outcomes, $+$ and $-$, we have $$P(D\cap +) + P(D \cap -) = P(D \cap(+ \cup -))= P(D) $$ So $P(D) = 0.009 + 0.001 = 0.010$.

Here $+ \cup -$ comprises of all possible options because those are the only two options for the test; it returns positive or negative and they are disjoint events. Moreover, if you have the disease, the test returns positive or negative so the probability of $D$ is sum of having the disease and the test returning positive and having the disease and the test returning negative.

Another way to write this is $$P(D) = P(D|+)P(+) + P(D|-)P(-) = P(D \cap +) + P(D \cap -)$$ if you read the next section of this book on conditional probability.

Comment: So this means that $\Omega \cap D = \emptyset$? If so, why the expression $P(D)$ has meaning?

Comment: @yong updated answer. Hopefully it is more clear...

Answer (score 1):

Analogize:

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be distinct events.

Let the probabilities of these events occurring be $p(E_1)$ and $p(E_2)$.

Let $p(E_1,E_2)$ denote the probability of events $E_1$ and $E_2$ both occurring.

Let $p(E_1, E_2^c)$ denote the probability that event $E_1$ occurs and event $E_2$ does not occur.

For purposes of this discussion, it is irrelevant whether events $E_1, E_2$ are independent events, or whether there is any association between them.

For example, event $E_1$ could be the event that it will rain tomorrow.  Event $E_2$ could be the event that you will flip a coin, and the coin will come up Heads, rather than Tails.

---

Suppose event $E_1$ occurs.  Then, you are guaranteed that exactly one of the two disjoint possibilities below occurred:

- $E_1,E_2$ both occurred : probability equals $p(E_1,E_2)$.
- $E_1,E_2^c$ both occurred : probability equals $p(E_1,E_2^c).$

The two events above are **disjoint**, and therefore, their probabilities are **additive**.

Therefore, $p(E_1) = p(E_1,E_2) + p(E_1,E_2^c).$